# Adding to a double-nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a double nested array in my MongoDB schema and I'm trying to add an entirely new array element to a second-level nested array using $push. I'm getting the error `cannot use the part (...) to traverse the element`

A documents have the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8e37eb46c064790a28a467"),
    "org-name" : "Manchester University NHS Foundation Trust",
    "domain" : "mft.nhs.uk",
    "subdomains" : [ {
            "name" : "careers.mft.nhs.uk",
            "firstSeen" : "2017-10-06 11:32:00",
            "history" : [
                {
                    "a_rr" : "80.244.185.184",
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-27T17:24:57.148Z"),
                    "asn" : 61323,
                    "asn_org" : "Ukfast.net Limited",
                    "city" : null,
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "shodan" : {
                        "ports" : [
                            {
                                "port" : 443,
                                "versions" : [
                                    "TLSv1",
                                    "-SSLv2",
                                    "-SSLv3",
                                    "TLSv1.1",
                                    "TLSv1.2",
                                    "-TLSv1.3"
                                ],
                                "cpe" : "cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.4.18",
                                "product" : "Apache httpd"

                                    }
                                  ],
                                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-27T17:24:58.538Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                ]
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is refresh the details held in the `history` array and add another entire array entry to represent the most recently collected data for the `subdomain.name`

The net result is that I will have multiple entries in the `history` array, each one timestamped the the date that the data was refreshed. That way I have a historical record of changes to any of the data held.

I've read that I can't use $push on a double-nested array but the other advice about using arrayfilters all appear to be related to updating an entry in an array rather than simply appending an entirely new document - unless I'm missing something!

I'm using PyMongo and would simply like to build a new dictionary containing all of the data elements and simply append it to the history.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward in pymongo:

```
record = db.mycollection.find_one()
record['subdomains'][0]['history'].append({'another': 'record'})
db.mycollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record)
```

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in exactly the right direction and it now works a treat! I had considered using this sort of approach but wasn't sure about the efficiency of replacing the entire record vs. simply updating an element of it. My dataset isn't large so probably doesn't make much difference. Thanks again!